# Is there a way to remove the (Minutes Summary) from a bookings form on WooBookings?

Tags: php

I am trying to setup my booking system using WooBookings.
My business offers bookings in blocks of 1 hour, with a minimum of 2 hours, and a buffer period of 15 minutes after a booking.

From what I can see, the buffer settings are dictated by the type of "Blocks" ie. Minutes, Hours, Days etc.

So, If I have blocks of Hours, I can only input the buffer time in Hours also.
The solution to this seems to be to change the blocks to minutes.
eg. Blocks of 60 Minutes, Buffer 10 Minutes.

However, on the front end, this then produces a time slot summary of 120 minutes for a 2 hour booking, or 600 minutes for 10 hours etc.

I would like to remove the (XX Minutes) completely from this dropdown.

I was able to find another code here: https://www.thathandsomebeardedguy.com/remove-cost-from-woocommerce-bookings-resource-dropdown/

That solved a similar problem for varied costs for resources which removed the (+$xx) from the resourse selection field, so i'm hoping this would be a similar solution needed here that could pick a pattern (xx - Minutes) and replace it with nothing.
But I have no ability to write this at all :(
[Capture of current booking calendar with notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB08s.jpg)

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

```
function handsomebeardedguy_booking_form_fields( $fields ) {
    if ( isset( $fields['wc_bookings_field_resource'] ) ) {
        $pattern = '#\(\+*.*\)#';
        $replacement = '';
        foreach ( $fields['wc_bookings_field_resource']['options'] as $key => $value ) {
            $fields['wc_bookings_field_resource']['options'][ $key ] = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $value );
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what `$fields['wc_bookings_field_resource']['options']` is supposed to contain here? (`var_export` or JSON, so that people can directly use it for test code.)

Comment: Hi CBroe, Thank you for the reply! I'm not really sure what this means... Could you give me any steps on how to give an example like this? Sorry, I'm really not familiar with this :/

Comment: `var_export` is a function to create a _code_ representation of a variable. So if you put `var_export($fields['wc_bookings_field_resource']);` into your function there, that should give you a result that you can directly copy&paste into your question. It has the advantage over other forms of debug output (var_dump, print_r), that people can directly use this _as code_, when they try to reproduce or debug your problem.